# Array Combine with keys php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. i want to set first array as keys and 2nd array as values. in keys i have only 6 values.

Array for keys.

```
Array ( [0] => id [1] => creditcard [2] => annualfee [3] => regularapr [4] => purchaseapr [5] => balancetransferapr )
```

Array for Values

```
Array ( [0] => id [1] => creditcard [2] => annualfee [3] => regularapr [4] => purchaseapr [5] =>
balancetransferapr
[6] => 1 [7] => Discover it Cash Back [8] => $10 [9] =>
11.99% - 22.99% variable
[10] => 0% for 14 months Valin Link [11] => 0% for 14 months [12] => 2 [13] =>
Chase Freedom Unlimited
[14] => $20 [15] => 22.99 - 22.74% Variable [16] =>
0% Intro APR on Purchases for 15 months
[17] => N/A [18] => 3 [19] => Chase Freedom Flex [20] => $30 [21] => 33.99 - 33.74% Variable [22] =>
0% Intro APR on Purchases for 15 months
[23] => N/A [24] => 4 [25] => Discover it Cash Back [26] => $10 [27] =>
44.99% - 44.99% variable
..........
```

I used `array_combine(keys, values)` but getting null result.

How can i set keys for value to get same result as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
            [creditcard] => creditcard
            [annualfee] => annualfee
            [regularapr] => regularapr
            [purchaseapr] => purchaseapr
            [balancetransferapr] => balancetransferapr
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [creditcard] => Discover it Cash Back
            [annualfee] => $10
            [regularapr] => 11.99% - 22.99% variable
            [purchaseapr] => 0% for 14 months Valin Link
            [balancetransferapr] => 0% for 14 months
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split your array into chunks of size of `keys` array:

```
$keys = [/* some keys here */];

$data = [/* full data */];

$chunks = array_chunk($data, count($keys));
// throw away first chunk as it holds field names
array_shift($chunks);

$result = [];
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $result[] = array_combine($keys, $chunk);
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/85dW0).

Answer (score 1):

A simple foreach loop with a condition does the trick

```
$ctr=0;
foreach($b as $bb) {
  $combo[$a[$ctr]] = $bb;    
  if ($ctr === count($a)-1) { $combos[]=$combo; $combo=[]; $ctr=0; } else $ctr++;
}

print_r($combos);
```

Example: https://www.tehplayground.com/awBLisBuiJj0ppSP

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => id
            [creditcard] => creditcard
            [annualfee] => annualfee
            [regularapr] => regularapr
            [purchaseapr] => purchaseapr
            [balancetransferapr] => balancetransferapr
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [creditcard] => Discover it Cash Back
            [annualfee] => $10
            [regularapr] => 11.99% - 22.99% variable
            [purchaseapr] => 0% for 14 months Valin Link
            [balancetransferapr] => 0% for 14 months
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [creditcard] => Chase Freedom Unlimited
            [annualfee] => $20
            [regularapr] => 22.99 - 22.74% Variable
            [purchaseapr] => 0% Intro APR on Purchases for 15 months
            [balancetransferapr] => N/A
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [creditcard] => Chase Freedom Flex
            [annualfee] => $30
            [regularapr] => 33.99 - 33.74% Variable
            [purchaseapr] => 0% Intro APR on Purchases for 15 months
            [balancetransferapr] => N/A
        )

)
```